# binding data in list box control and retrieving the seleced value id

Tags: asp.net

I have list box control where I am binding the values to the listbox

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Employees");
ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Employees"].DefaultView; 
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
ListBox1.DataTextField = "FirstName";
ListBox1.DataValueField = "StaffID";
ListBox1.Databind();
```

after select ing the  value  .
I have button  once the user  clicks  this

```
protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
  {       
 var selectedItems = (from item in listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()     where item.Selected        select item.Text).ToArray();   
     result.Text = "You selected: ";    
   result.Text += string.Join(",", selectedItems); 
   }
```

Right now I    code inside the  event  gives me the  selected  vlaues  name.
  but I  want to get the  selected   values  index
ex

```
ID  NAME
23  ram
34 tom
67 john
```

so  if I select  ram and  john
  in  code  behind  I  need  to get these  vales  ID that is 23,  67

Hope  my question is clear

Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to iterate your listbox items like..

```
 foreach (ListItem lstItem in lstProduct.Items)
    {
        if (lstItem.Selected)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there  was  a  small change to  be  made       to  make this work

```
protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var selectedItems = (from item in listBox.Items.Cast() where item.Selected select **item.Value**).ToArray();
result.Text = "You selected: ";
result.Text += string.Join(",", selectedItems);
 }
```

this  line

```
var selectedItems = (from item in listBox.Items.Cast() where item.Selected select item.Value).ToArray();
```